# Mongoskin - How to convert primary key string to bson at mongodb fields _id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Mongodb default primary key is _id and it's type is bson .

ex: {_id : "4e7020cb7cac81af7136236b"}

I want to set another field's value as primary key .

ex: apple

How to convert  apple(it's type is string)
    to bson type and as a primary key ?

ex: apple (stirng) (convert)--> xxxx11112222333344445555 (bson)

```
{_id : "xxxx11112222333344445555"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't have to convert: according to the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/bson/#mongodb-document-types), you can write anything into `_id` providing it's unique within the collection.

So, in your case, you can just open mongo console and try the following:

```
a = db.yourCollectionNameHere.findOne(ObjectId('4e7020cb7cac81af7136236b'));
a._id = a.apple;
db.yourCollectionNameHere.save(a);
db.tokens.findOne({_id: 'xxxx11112222333344445555'});
```

(with your collection name and the id value in the last line).